# Acceder a los atributos de un marco web

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero acceder a los atributos que se cargan en un `<iframe>`, pero me sale este error:

> Error: Permission denied to access property

Tengo entendido que es por el cruce de dominios, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo con *jQuery* o *Javascript*.

Dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```js
document.getElementById( iUno ).onload = function(){ 
  iframe = window.frames.iUno; 
  iframe.play(); 
};
```

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Dar play a reproductor</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <iframe id="iUno" name="iUno" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0..." frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: veo que te faltan doble comillas: `document.getElementById("iUno")`.....

Comment: Los `iframe`s no tienen ningún método `play` por lo que `iframe.play();` no debería hacer nada (o debería mostrar un mensaje de error)

Comment: Si, pero el error no es de que la funcion no exista, lo que pasa esque no puedo acceder a ningun atrubuto del iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo, en el que puedes acceder al `iframe` desde su `id`

```js
var elementoIframe=document.getElementById("iUno");// aca te faltaba las comillas
console.log(elementoIframe);
```

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title>Dar play a reproductor</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <iframe id="iUno" src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
  </body> 
</html>
```